# Javascript - Open page as _blank instead of pop up

Tags: javascript, redirect, checkout, whmcs

In my Billing CMS (WHMCS) there's a page that redirects you to another page.

The problem is that this redirected page is being opened as a Pop Up, and I'm looking for the source of it to make it open in target="blank" instead.

This is the redirect script I found in the page that originates the pop up:

```
<script language="javascript">
setTimeout ( "autoForward()" , 0 );
function autoForward() {
    var submitForm = $("#submitfrm").find("form");
    submitForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

Can this function trigger the Pop Up? Is there a way to change it to _blank by adding something to the code above? If not, what should I look for to find the source of this function?

Thanks!!

Comment: This script doesn't actually directly open the pop-up.

Comment: If the form in question has `target="_blank"` or `target="anything"` it would open a popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over that function, set the form's `target`

```
function autoForward() {
    var submitForm = $("#submitfrm").find("form");
    submitForm.prop('target', '_blank');
    submitForm.submit();
}
```

Here is the documentation on [target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp).